# Wordpress post->ID Problem

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a wordpress question. I am trying to use a bit of code that works just fine on my home page on my inner page templates:

```
query_posts('cat=4');
    // The Loop
    echo '<div id="cal_details"><ul>';
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $cal_date_j = date('j', intval(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_value', true)));
        $cal_date_n = date('n', intval(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_value', true)));
            $my_array[] = date('j, n', intval(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_value', true)));


            $issetdate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_value', true);

            if (isset($issetdate)) {
            echo '<li class="cal_event_li list_item_' . $cal_date_j . '_' . $cal_date_n . '">';
            echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
            the_title();                        
                echo '</a></li>';
            }
    endwhile;
    echo '</ul></div>';
```

However, this doesn't seem to work on the inner-pages. All the titles links are being outputted correctly but it won't print the get_post_meta part correctly.

The list items all display something like `<li class="cal_event_li list_item_1_1">`

I think there is perhaps some issue with the way I have tried to use $post->ID but Im not sure whats going on here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `query_posts` you have to call `global $post` to get the post_meta.  If you're only calling one category why don't you just use an archive template?

Also if you're going to use `query_posts` make sure you reset the query afterwords so plugins, sidebars, etc can still interact with the loop for conditionals etc..

```
global %post;
query_posts('cat=4');
    // The Loop
    //more stuff
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: THe code is for a plugin that feeds dates into a calendar on the sidebar, thats why I can't use an archives page.

Answer (score -1):

try replacing $post->ID with the_ID() in the inner pages. something like this

```
query_posts('cat=4');
// The Loop
echo '<div id="cal_details"><ul>';
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $cal_date_j = date('j', intval(get_post_meta(the_ID(), 'date_value', true)));
    $cal_date_n = date('n', intval(get_post_meta(the_ID(), 'date_value', true)));
        $my_array[] = date('j, n', intval(get_post_meta(the_ID(), 'date_value', true)));


        $issetdate = get_post_meta(the_id(), 'date_value', true);

        if (isset($issetdate)) {
        echo '<li class="cal_event_li list_item_' . $cal_date_j . '_' . $cal_date_n . '">';
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
        the_title();                        
            echo '</a></li>';
        }
endwhile;
echo '</ul></div>';
```